# Symbol table debug information is not added in dll (delphi) after build it from CMD dcc32

Tags: delphi-2010

I am trying to generate a `.TDS` file for a `.DLL` compiled with the command-line `dcc32.exe` compiler and a `.CFG` configuration file.

At the time of converting, I see that my DLL file does not have a symbol table. To cross check this, I check the size of the DLL before and after compiling, and it is the same. Please tell me what I am missing in my `.CFG` file that prevents symbol table debug information from being added to the DLL.

I am using Delphi 10.  My `.CFG` file is as follows:

```
/B
/H-
/GD
/W-
/$A+
/$B-
/$C-
/$D+
/$E-
/$F-
/$G+
/$H+
/$I+
/$J+
/$K-
/$L+
/$M-
/$N+
/$O+
/$P+
/$Q+
/$R+
/$S+
/$T-
/$U-
/$V-
/$W+
/$X+
/$Y+
/AWinTypes=Windows;WinProcs=Windows;DbiTypes=BDE;DbiProcs=BDE;DbiErrs=BDE;
/$M16384,2097152
/K4194300
/NSData.Win;Datasnap.Win;Web.Win;Soap.Win;Xml.Win;System;Xml;Data;Datasnap;Web;Soap;System.Win;Winapi;Vcl;Vcl.Samples;Vcl.Imaging
/CC
/DTDMDLL;BOMDLL;TRACE_INPUTBOX;
/IH:\Shared\INC
/UH:\Shared\PAS\PasController
/UH:\Shared\VCL
/UH:\Shared\VCL\TMS\Current\TMSComponentPack
/UH:\3rdParty\Delphi
/UH:\Tlbs
/UH:\3rdParty\HyperAct
/UH:\3rdParty\GifImage
/UH:\3rdParty\Abbrevia2\Product
/UH:\3rdParty\Microsoft
/UH:\3rdParty\Microsoft\IExtractImage
/UH:\Shared\INC
/UH:\Shared\Pas
/UH:\Shared\Internal
/UH:\\Shared\VCL\ElPack\Code
/UH:\Shared\VCL\ElPack\Code\Design
/UH:\Shared\VCL\QR1
/UH:\Shared\VCL\ElPack\Code\Source
/UH:\Shared\VCL\ShortcutBar
/UH:\Shared\VCL\Hebrew
/UH:\Shared\VCL\ToolBar
/UH:\Shared\VCL\PlasmaTools\Src
/UH:\Shared\DataModelDesign\InDbFunctions
/UH:\Shared\DataModelDesign\DistributedDesign
/UH:\Shared\DataModelDesign\DataModelDesigner
/UH:\Shared\BldKit\PUBLIC\KitRes\PAS
/UH:\Shared\VCL\xBom
/UH:\Shared\VCL\xDiff
/UH:\Shared\VCL\DEVEXP~1\Current\EXPRES~3\Sources
 -RH:\Shared\VCL -RH:\Shared\BldKit\VER
;Append Project Local Setting
/U H:\Shared\VCL\DevExpress\Current\ExpressBars 5\Sources\ 
/UH:\BOM\SmartBomConsolidation
```

Also, how can I can generate a `.PDB` file for the DLL?

Comment: No, you can't generate a pdb file. There are some third party tools that attempt to do this but with limited success in my experience.

Comment: ok, what to do for Symbol table debug information is not added in dll after build it?

Comment: I've no idea what version you use. The tag says 2010

Comment: I don't have a Delphi compiler on this system, but if memory serves you need a /V switch for having Turbo Debugger symbols generated.

Comment: @500-InternalServerError: the command-line compiler has a `-V` switch to generate debug info in the executable, and a `-VT` switch to generate debug info in a `TDS` file. In the shown .`CFG` file, `/$V-` is not for debug info, it is disabling "strict var-strings" instead.

Comment: @RemyLebeau i need to use -VT switch to generate debug info. is it that you are saying ?